# Laravel reCaptcha integration

Tags: php, laravel, recaptcha

I would like to implement reCaptcha in my Laravel project **without** using Laravel packages. I have tried with classical reCaptcha V2 which works, but I would like to implement invisible reCaptcha instead.

So what I did is this:

```
<form id="subscribeForm" class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="/subscribe" style="margin-bottom:70px;">
    ...
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{{trans('content.input_submit')}}</button>

    <div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="---my---key---" data-size="invisible" data-callback="onSubmit"></div>

    <script> ...callback functions... </script>
</form>
```

I got the floating reCaptcha bar on the right appear correctly, but of course since I need a button to perform actual submission I have a button with type submit, and none of the callback functions from reCaptcha div get triggered. When I return the request I get `g-recaptcha-response` empty.

Why doesn't it get submitted independent of the callback?

Comment: Here is the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66720254/google-recaptcha-with-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The callback function of reCaptcha doesn't get triggered*, that depends where you have defined your callback function.

It shouldn't be defined inside `$(document).ready()` or `window.onload` scope

To submit the captcha token to the server, place an hidden input field within your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="reCaptchaToken" value="" id="reCaptchaToken">
```

Replace the submit button with a regular button so that the form isn't submitted, remove the captcha `<div>` as it isn't needed.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-callback='onSubmit'>{{trans('content.input_submit')}}</button>
```

and you could populate the value using the callback function and submit the form

```
// Google reCaptcha callback
function onSubmit (res) {
    document.getElementById("reCaptchaToken").value = res;
    document.getElementById("subscribeForm").submit();
}
```

and access the captcha token in the controller using `Input::get('reCaptchaToken')`

Comment: But there is no `data-sitekey` in your code. How am I supposed to get Google response this way? This is just a generic way to populate a hidden field, not to get reCaptcha to function properly?

Comment: You have `data-sitekey` in your recaptcha `div` You need to add this hidden input field

Comment: Oh..now I see that this is input only. The problem is that `data-callback` doesn't do anything. I don't know if there is some special way to register a function, because one inside the script doesn't get called. It is even grey in my IDE as if it is not used

Comment: Well maybe because you are submitting the form before the data callback is getting called.

Comment: How to avoid that?

Comment: Hide or disable the submit button on init and enable it in your callback function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145452/discussion-between-norgul-and-linktoahref).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it properly by extending the `Validator`, however this solution uses the google/recaptcha package (which is much more elegant than using CURL).

```
composer require google/recaptcha "~1.1"
```

Create a new config value for `recaptcha_secret_key` and `recaptcha_site_key` in `config/app.php` or another custom config file.

In `AppServiceProvider` `boot()` method:

```
Validator::extend('recaptcha', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $recaptcha = new ReCaptcha(config('app.recaptcha_secret_key'));
    $resp = $recaptcha->verify($value, request()->ip());

    return $resp->isSuccess();
});
```

In `resources/lang/validation.php` add:

```
'recaptcha' => 'The :attribute answer is invalid.',
```

Also, add this to the `attributes` array inside the same file in order to make the error message nicer:

```
'g-recaptcha-response' => 'reCAPTCHA',
```

In the view file you want to display the reCAPTCHA e.g. `contact.blade.php`:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{{ config('app.recaptcha_site_key') }}"></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

Add `data-size="invisible"` etc. to the div if you want it invisible.

Finally, add the new validation rule to your controller:

```
'g-recaptcha-response' => 'recaptcha'
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last part about the validation rule in a controller? Where exactly should that line go? I'm submitting my contact form via a POST web route. My reCaptcha shows up without that last line in place anywhere (`'g-recaptcha-response' => 'recaptcha'`), but the form isn't prevented from submitting when the checkbox isn't checked.