# Add recaptcha to default Laravel Password Reset

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, recaptcha, change-password

I want to require the users of my Laravel 5.1 application to have finished a Google Recaptcha process, but I can't figure out how to safely modify the code that sends the reset password link.

The code that does this for me is the "postEmail()" function in the inherited trait "ResetsPassword". This is my entire PasswordController:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller {

use ResetsPasswords;

/**
 * Create a new password controller instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard  $auth
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker  $passwords
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Guard $auth, PasswordBroker $passwords)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->passwords = $passwords;

    $this->middleware('guest');
}

}
```

As you can see, all the real methods are in the "ResetsPasswords" trait which is in a vendor file so I don't want to modify it directly. How do I modify the "postEmail()" function in the inherited trait safely in my PasswordsController?

Comment: What about extending the vendor Class? Just a thought, not ready for an answer.

Answer (score 7):

In your `ForgotPasswordController` add this method:

```
protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'recaptcha',
    ]);
}
```

And follow my reCAPTCHA implementation guide here: [Laravel reCaptcha integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258290/laravel-recaptcha-integration/44703488#44703488)

Comment: Perfect, just as I like answers: Small, exact and working! 
I saw that maybe laravel 6 changed, but now in the trait `SendsPasswordResetEmails.php` it runs `$request->validate([...])` instead of  `$this->validate($request,[...])` but I think that's just a small change and will probably work both ways.

Comment: Or if you want a nice error message (tested in Laravel 8 but works for older versions as well): 
´´´
    protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'recaptcha',
        ],
        [
            'g-recaptcha-response.recaptcha' => 'Captcha failed.'
        ]);
    }
´´´

Answer (score 1):

Add the code to **Auth/ForgotPasswordController.ph**p

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset emails and
    | includes a trait which assists in sending these notifications from
    | your application to your users. Feel free to explore this trait.
    |
    */

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha',
        ]);
    }
}
```