# Add reCAPTCHA to ForgotPasswordController

Tags: laravel, recaptcha

If I follow the answer in this question:

[Add recaptcha to default Laravel Password Reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526408/add-recaptcha-to-default-laravel-password-reset)

and add the below function to the ForgotPasswordController to override the validation in the Trait

```
protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email',
    'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
    ]);
}
```

I get the following error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController::validateEmail() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given

But if I modify the SendPasswordResetEmails trait directly by adding the following to the validateEmail function:

```
'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
```

reCAPTCHA is required on validation and the password reset form works correctly. **Problem is, I know you are not supposed to modify Traits directly.**

What do I need to do to be able to require reCAPTCHA on the password reset form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the following to my Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```