# Implementing reCaptcha in Laravel 8.2

Tags: php, laravel, recaptcha

I went through all the steps of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44703488/432321) by @kjdion84, but I don't know what is meant by the last part:

> Finally, add the new validation rule to your controller:
>
> `'g-recaptcha-response' => 'recaptcha'`

This is my first Laravel project, and I don't know what to use as "my controller." I want to implement reCaptcha on my contact form, the action of which sends an email. The form itself is on contact.blade.php, and the submission is handled via a POST route like so (in **web.php**):

```
Route::post('/contact', function(Request $request) {
    Mail::to('<my email address>')->send(new ContactMail($request));
    return redirect()->route('thank-you');
});
```

**ContactMail** is in app/Http/Mail and is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ContactMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $email;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->email = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Contact form submission')
                    ->from($this->email->email, $this->email->name)
                    ->to('<my email address>')
                    ->view('email.contactmail');
    }
}
```

Everything works with the form functionality; I just can't figure out how to actually get the reCaptcha validation in place. (See the linked answer from the beginning of my question for information on where I put other reCaptcha stuff.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a closure instead of a dedicated controller, you could add the validation rule to the request object as:

```
Route::post('/contact', function(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'recaptcha'
    ]);

    Mail::to('<my email address>')->send(new ContactMail($request));

    return redirect()->route('thank-you');
});
```

*PS: It is better to use a Controller than a Closure for complex calculations*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give that a try. is `validate()` a function I need to add/write, or was it put in when I installed reCaptcha via Composer? Also, do you have a helpful link for explaining Closures vs Controllers, and why what I'm doing isn't best practice? (Sorry—Laravel newbie.)

Comment: `validate()` is a function that you need to add to the function. You don't want to clutter your routes file with application code, which is the job of the Controller, which is I intended to separate the code to a Controller method.

Comment: Gotcha. So, any guidance on what I need to put in my `validate()` function? And do I need to create a new controller for this, or use one that came "out of the box" with Laravel? Sorry for being such a novice with this.

Comment: The validation [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation) got you covered